# CentOS failed to install anaconda linux ppc64le (Virtual machine)

Tags: centos, anaconda

The following are some of the work I did when I installed it.

- python version

[root@centos7 App Store]# `python --version`

Python 2.7.5

- CentOS 64bit

[root@centos7 App Store]# `uname -a`

Linux centos7 3.10.0-514.el7.`x86_64` #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

- install anaconda, a warning...

[root@centos7 App Store]# `./Anaconda2-4.4.0.1-Linux-ppc64le.sh`

`WARNING`:
    Machine does not appear to be ppc64le.  This software was sepicically
    build for POWER8 running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
    Are sure you want to continue the installation? [yes|no]

[no] >>> yes

- installation results, failed.

./Anaconda2-4.4.0.1-Linux-ppc64le.sh: line 489: /root/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.13-0/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
`ERROR`:
cannot execute native linux-ppc64le binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
Linux centos7 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---

Is my version matching wrong? Or because I am in the `virtual machine`(VM,VMware Workstation) inside?

I saw other problems on the Stack Overflow, most of the reason is due to `version does not match`, I seem not the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded a different version `Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`, not for `Anaconda2-4.4.0.1-Linux-ppc64le.sh` The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Power8 is a family of super scalar symmetric multiprocessors, Designed to be a massively multi threaded chips, with each of its cores capable of handling eight hardware threads simultaneously.

If your server is not power8 processor based, please download Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh this installer.

**To install it on ubuntu:**

bash Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh